# Why does mongoose ObjectId.valueOf() return an object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[According to the mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/) ObjectId.valueOf() is supposed to now return a string version of the id.

However, I'm using mongoose (v3.8.12) and the valueOf() function is returning an object.

I know that this changed in v2.2 of mongodb, but it's been a while since then.

**Can anyone explain why this is the case? Or point me to some definitive documentation about the mongoose behaviour?**

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You provided a link to mongodb shell documentation.

However, what you're actually using is a node.js implementation, specifically [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) ORM build on top of [mongodb native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native). And `mongodb-native`, for its part, is using [bson](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bson) module.

So, instead of mongodb shell documentation you should be looking at `mongoose` and `mongodb-native` docs:

- [`mongoose` API documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)
- [`mongodb-native` and `bson` docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)

Here is a [documentation for `ObjectId` class](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) `mongoose` and `mongodb-native` are using.

As for `.valuOf()` method, it's a part of [JavaScript Object prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) and has nothing to do with either `mongoose` or `mongodb-native`.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I know I should be checking mongoose and node driver docs, just couldn't find a reference to this.  I'm just surprised that there's such difference in behaviour between the shell and the official node driver - it's all JS after all.  Yes valueof is a standard JS object function, but it can be (and often is) overridden.